# Background service with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I want to create a background service with Cordova, is there any plugin that can help me with this? I want to check the user's SMS when it receives an SMS even if the application is closed and and when the application was open I can get those SMS, only for Android, iOS that Apple does not allow, someone has some way so that I can do this? grateful.

Comment: What did you end up doing since you didn't select Mohammand's response as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I already done it before. You need to use this cordova plugin, https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService.

My finish product you can check it here

- http://www.revivalx.com/my/smsmanager/
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nurdin.smsmanager